# Orange canvas does not show any icon

Tags: icons, python-3.4, orange

I installed python3.4.3, orange3 on my win10(x64) laptop but no icon shows up...[this was what I saw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqLIF.jpg)

Comment: Did you install Orange 3 using the official installer from orange.biolab.si? If so did you have Python and/or PyQt4 already installed before?

Comment: Yes I use the official installer. I had installed Python3.5(64) before, and I installed Python3.4.3(32), which is recommended by the installer. I hadn't installed PyQt4 before (or perhaps I had without my consciousness).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually indicates a broken/misconfigured PyQt4 installation. Qt4 supports .svg icons by means of a runtime plugin library which is installed alongside PyQt4. However if Qt4 fails to find and load this plugin SVG icons are unavailable and simply will not be displayed.

To see whether SVG icons can be loaded run the following from the command prompt (adjusting the python.exe path according to your installation layout):

```
C:\Python34\python.exe -c "from PyQt4.QtGui import QImageReader; print([bytes(fmt).decode('ascii') for fmt in QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()])"
```

If the output does not include a "svg" string, then svg icons can not be loaded.

Also run

```
C:\Python34\python.exe -c "from PyQt4.QtCore import QLibraryInfo; print(QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.PluginsPath))"
```

This will print the root directory from where the Qt4 plugins are loaded. This should be `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins` (for the default python installation). If not try creating a `C:\Python34\qt.conf` file containing:

```
[PATHS]
Prefix = Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt4
```

[qt.conf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100248799/qt.conf)

Comment: "svg" is not included, and the second result is:
X:\Qt487-vc10-x32\plugins . 

By the way, I found the commend work only if I exchange <"> and <'>.

Comment: I fixed the quotes, thank you. Can you check the updated answer (regarding qt.conf)?